# How to add rules in Jason while running

Tags: prolog, agent, multi-agent

I am wondering how to add a new rule in Jason. In prolog it would be just something like:

```
a :- b, c.
```

In Jason I have tried something that [was discussed in jason users list](https://sourceforge.net/p/jason/mailman/message/702885/), with no success:

```
a :- b & c.
+a :- b & c.
+(a :- b & c).
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
+{a :- b & c}.
```

And you can check if it worked:

```
{.relevant_rules(_,L);.print(L);}
```

By the way, if you want to remove it, you can do as following:

```
-{a :- b & c}.
```

Comment: Is there a way to test this rule when it is not part of a context?

Comment: Why .send(self, tellRule, [{a :- b & c}]). does not work?